# Can't sort array of structures alphabetically

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, structure

I am trying to sort strings in an array of structures alphabetically then print, but my code doesn't work.

I've been trying to figure out why for the past few hours, but can't figure it out. I'm sure its probably something super obvious, but I've only been programming for a few weeks and I can't figure it out.

It does compile with no errors, the output is just a print of the original unsorted array but without aardvark, like so:                                                                             boy
acumen
addle
cat
affix
agar
ahoy
aigrette
ajar

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    char    word[15];
    char    definition[50];
};
struct entry dictionary[100] = 
  { {"boy",         "a boy          "                   },
    {"aardvark",    "a burrowing African mammal"        },
    {"acumen",      "mentally sharp; keen"              },
    {"addle",       "to become confused"                },
    {"cat",         "a cat"                             },
    {"affix",       "to append; attach"                 },
    {"agar",        "a jelly made from seaweed"         },
    {"ahoy",        "a nautical call of greeting"       },
    {"aigrette",    "an ornamental cluster of feathers" },
    {"ajar",        "partially opened"                  } 
  };



int main(void)
{
    int i;
    void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[]);

    dictionarySort(dictionary);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dictionary[i].word);
    }

    return 0;
}

void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[])
{
    int i, k, j;
    struct entry temp[100];

    for(i = 0; i <=  9; ++i)
    {
        for( k = 0; dictionary[i].word[k] != '\0'; ++k)
        {
            if( (dictionary[i].word[k] > dictionary[i+1].word[k] ) )
            {
                temp[i] = dictionary[i];
                dictionary[i] = dictionary[i+1];
                dictionary[i+1] = temp[i];
            }

        }

    }
}
```

If anyone has any input I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does it compile? If so, what happens when you run it? If not, what error do you get on compiling?

Comment: It does compile with no errors, the output is just a print of the original unsorted array but without aardvark, like so:                                                                             boy
acumen
addle
cat
affix
agar
ahoy
aigrette
ajar

Comment: Problem 1: you haven't shown us how `struct entry` is defined, but if this is C and `word` is a `char *`, then your comparison `if(dictionary[i].word[k] > dictionary[i+1].word[k] )` is not going to work.  You're going to have to call `strcmp` instead.

Comment: `i <=  9` --> `i <  9`

Comment: Also, if you just want to get sorted output (as opposed to learn how to implement sort algorithms), it's often much easier to call the library function `qsort`.  We can how you how to do that, if you want.

Comment: the code is using the 'magic' number 9 for a counter of the number of entries in the table.   That is very error prone, especially when the number of entries changes.   Suggest: 'int NumEntries = sizeof(dictionary)/sizeof(dictionary[0])' and use 'numEntries' everywhere the number 9 is currently being used.   Then, there are no 100 entries, but, given the current code, is what will be tried to be sorted.  Suggest: 'struct entry dictionary[] ='  I.E. let the compiler figure out the actual number of entries.

Comment: do not bury the prototype for the sub function inside the main() function.  because when the compiler gets to the sub function, it will not have a proper knowledge of what the sub function parameters are.   Suggest: place the prototype before the main() function.

Comment: strings are compared with something like strcmp(), not '=='.   strings are copied with something like: strcpy(), not '='.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the algorithm you are trying to build is not sorting. What you have here is (after fixing issues described below) one iteration of bubble sort. To make it actually sort the array you need to call `dictioarySort` 10 times. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort for more details.

Now to the other issues in the code. You can simplify your entire loop by just using `strcmp`:

```
for(i = 0; i <=  9; ++i)
{
    if( strcmp(dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i+1].word ) > 0 )
    {
        temp[i] = dictionary[i];
        dictionary[i] = dictionary[i+1];
        dictionary[i+1] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

But if you are making some kind of an exercise and want to figure out how to do it your way, there are two issues with your logic:

1. Consider words "azc" and "brc". They are in alphabetical order, so they don't need to be swapped. After you look at their first characters, `a` and `b` correspondingly, you should stop comparing them. Instead you continue to the next letter, `z` and `r` correspondingly, and decide to swap them based on that, leading to an incorrect order.
2. After you swap two words, you should also stop. Consider a case of `za`, `rb`. After looking at the first letters, `z` and `r`, you will swap the words (which is good). But then you will look at the second letters. This time the words are already swapped, so you will look at `b` and `a`, and swap them again. So the full solution will be along the lines of:

```
for(i = 0; i <=  9; ++i)
{
    for( k = 0; dictionary[i].word[k] != '\0'; ++k)
    {
        if( (dictionary[i].word[k] > dictionary[i+1].word[k] ) )
        {
            temp[i] = dictionary[i];
            dictionary[i] = dictionary[i+1];
            dictionary[i+1] = temp[i];
            break; // <<-- this is new
        }
        else if( (dictionary[i].word[k] < dictionary[i+1].word[k] ) )
        {
            break; // <<-- this is new
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am working an exercise from a book and it hasn't covered strcmp yet. Your answer improved the result, but for some reason the entry for boy is still stuck between addle and affix, but the entry for cat has been moved to its proper place.

Comment: That is expected, if you still call only **one** iteration of your algorithm. One iteration of your algorithm only "bubbles" one biggest element to the top. What happened is that `boy` was "bubbled" to where the "cat" was, and then the "cat" was bubbled all the way to the top. As I suggested at the beginning of my answer, you need to run your sort 10 times to actually sort your array.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I missed the first part of your comment where you said it was only one iteration. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use strcmp() to compare strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Entry {
    char    word[15];
    char    definition[50];
};

struct Entry dictionary[100] =  {
    {"boy",         "a boy          "                   },
    {"aardvark",    "a burrowing African mammal"        },
    {"acumen",      "mentally sharp; keen"              },
    {"addle",       "to become confused"                },
    {"cat",         "a cat"                             },
    {"affix",       "to append; attach"                 },
    {"agar",        "a jelly made from seaweed"         },
    {"ahoy",        "a nautical call of greeting"       },
    {"aigrette",    "an ornamental cluster of feathers" },
    {"ajar",        "partially opened"                  }
};



int main(void) {
    int i;
    void dictionarySort(struct Entry dictionary[]);
    dictionarySort(dictionary);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", dictionary[i].word);
    }
    return 0;
}

void dictionarySort(struct Entry dictionary[]) {
    int i, j;
    char temp[100];
    for(i = 0; i <=  9; ++i) {
        for(j = i + 1; j <= 9; j++) {
            if(strcmp(dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word) > 0) {
                strcpy(temp, dictionary[i].word);
                strcpy(dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word);
                strcpy(dictionary[j].word, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `word` and `definition` must be together.